# JAXB changes XML order on server but not on localhost

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have an XML in the following format:

```xml
<products>
     <product>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>a</name>
          <price>24.5</price>
     </product>
     <product>
          <id>2</id>
          <name>b</name>
          <price>3.75</price>
     </product>
     .
     .
     .
</products>
```

I'm using JAXB to get the data from the XML.

this is how the xsd looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="products">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="product"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="product">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="id"/>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="price"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:schema>
```

My problem is that on localhost I get the products one by one like in the XML (id 1 than id 2 etc.) But when I upload it to my amazon server (linux), I get different ordering and I cannot understand why.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: No clear idea as to why. If you publish your POJO it will be easier to  investigate.

Answer (score 2):

By default [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations do not define an order.  This means that the behaviour may different between Java VMs.  There are a couple of options for defining an order.

**Option #1 - `@XmlType(propOrder={"foo", "bar})`**

Using this annotation at the class level allows you to specify the order in which you want to see the XML elements marshalled to XML.

**Option #2 - `@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)`**

You can use the `@XmlAccessorOrder` annotation at the class level to specify that you want to see the XML elements marshalled to XML in alphabetical order.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the xml ordering?
I don't want to order the elements at all, I just want to read the elements one by one in the same order that they arrive in the xml.

Comment: @ItayD - You mean the contents of the `product` collection is different?  If so what type of collection class are you using?

Comment: the content is not different, just the ordering. Let's say that in the XML, the product with <id>2</id> is before the product with <id>1</id>, so on server side I'm getting <id>1</id> before <id>2</id> which is not the order that was in XML.
I added the XSD to my question so you can see the collection.

Comment: What is the type of the Java property that holds onto the products?

Comment: I have: List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<Product>(); I add each product to that list. But even before adding it to the list, I wrote the id's into a log file, and there I saw that the ordering is not correct.